# FOS BUNDLE throws error with Fr3d Bundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, fr3dldapbundle

I have used FOS USER BUNDLE along with Fr3d LDAP bundle. When I try to login, I'm getting the error

> Unrecognized field: usernameCanonical

I need your help

Comment: I doubt its an issue with Fr3d LDAP bundle, if you comment that bundle out of the AppKernel does it still throw the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems that your User class is not extending from the FOS Users's base class.

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use FR3D\LdapBundle\Model\LdapUserInterface;

class User extends BaseUser implements LdapUserInterface
```